# R - Convert raster to RGB image for use in photoshop or GIMP

Tags: r, image, photoshop, raster, gimp

I have some landsat 8 data that I would like to turn into a .png (or other lossless RGB) image file. Although I am very familiar with the raster package, I can't figure out how to write out an image without the georeferencing header information (which GIMP can't seem to handle).

For example the following writes out a geotiff without a problem, but I can't figure out how to get it into a format available to GIMP or photoshop.

```
library(raster)

B1 = raster("..//LC80800202014265LGN00_B1.TIF")
B1[B1>10000]=NA
B2 = raster("..//LC80800202014265LGN00_B2.TIF")
B2[B2>10000]=NA
B3 = raster("..//LC80800202014265LGN00_B3.TIF")
B3[B3>10000]=NA
d = stack(B1,B2,B3)
plotRGB(d, scale = 10000)
writeRaster((d/10000*255), filename="..//blue6.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Let me know if you have any ideas! Thanks

Comment: can you use `png(); plotRGB(); dev.off() `?

Comment: When you try to load the image in GIMP, you must get an error..what does it say??

Comment: png(); plotRGB(); dev.off() works but creates a very coarse representation even if I assign a number of rows and columns that matches the raster. Any ideas?